# Validate Signature of JWT that doesn't contain the 'kid' Header

Tags: node.js, jwt

The IdP I'm working with signs JWTs without adding the Key ID ('kid') header.

Additionally, keys are rotated quickly.

The [JWT RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517#page-8) says that the KID is indeed optional, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how I'm implementing proper signature validation without iterating through all keys that are returned from my IdPs JWKS URL and trying them out blindly.

Also I'm using [jwks-rsa](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa) that only supports `getSigningKey(<kid>)`.

I appreciate any hint about what's the proper approach here!

Comment: What's the IDP? What their docs say about it? What other clients do? A check against all known keys sounds like the only way if key change over time but no kid is present.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's Forgerock actually & I'm the first client, but I've got no insights into the platform. Just working with the ./well-known/openid-configuration endpoint. As the KID is really optional I thought there must be some other "standard approach" to how to handle this.

Comment: The best approach here would be then to contact them and ask them the very same question. Come back with their answer, though, as I am also interested in what the IdP believes you as the client should do in their scenario.

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor! I'll do exactly that.

Comment: Can you post a sample token in the question? What signature algorithm is used? RS256 or HS256?

Comment: Hi Tore. The problem solved itself. The issue was that those tokens were only Access Tokens that could only be checked through introspection. They didn't even contain a signature that could have been validated.